# Is there a way to fix these Disqus "preload" warnings?

Tags: javascript, disqus

Console shows me these warnings below on my webpage with Disqus comments:

Why is their script so full of warnings? Should I / can I even fix it?

[image]

Comment: I got that warnings also. I have try to get a support but this topic has not yet in Advice and answers from the [*Disqus Team*](https://help.disqus.com/?q=was%20preloaded%20using%20link%20preload%20but%20not%20used%20within)

Answer (score 4):

As I understand, it says that the browser preloads some resources that are not used afterwards on this page. If you don't like these warnings for some reason, try to get rid of something like (my guess)

```
<link rel="preload (or prerender)" href="//disqus.com">
```

in the `head` section of your html-template and keep me posted :) Probably, you should include preloading only on pages where disqus comments get actually loaded.

**PS.** I checked my site where disqus is used too. I don't use any library's/framework's component to load disqus comments though. Indeed, Disqus script adds this:

```
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://c.disquscdn.com/...">
```

in the `head` section for several resources. So, I think the reason given above is valid. Generally, it is browsers' stuff. I get warnings in Blink-based Google Chrome and Opera and empty console in Mozilla Firefox (Gecko-based) and Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML-based). In the end, don't worry - those are just warnings related to internal browser stuff caused by the way disqus script behaves - I think we cannot change it (unless you just remove the whole disqus stuff from your site).

Comment: Well, I didn't preload anything myself, their script gets preloaded for some reason, I don't know why. It seems like my router works properly and loads resources only when you go on that page

Comment: could you share the link?

Comment: I'm using this Vue component in my project (it doesn't seem to have any preloading in there, or at least I don't see it): https://github.com/ktquez/vue-disqus/blob/master/VueDisqus.vue

Comment: I've sent an email to their support about this, but heard nothing back (that was several months ago)